# pause/resume(range specific request ) download does not work on safari

Tags: safari, download, resume

I have implemented download pause/resume on vb.net using code given here [VB.net Forum](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/22533) 
It works on IE, Chrome, Firefox and Free Download manager but it is not working on Safari. I tried to debug it using a different file which is hosted a tomcat behind apache server and compared headers return by the servers.  only difference is Etag I am not generating unique for each file on vb.net. I googled a lot but I couldn't find anything specific to safari. Is there any safari specific header I am missing? I don't mind if the solution is on any other platform I will convert it to vb

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of some safari bug, as soon as I updated safari on both Mac and windows it worked.